# How to cache coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, caching, google-maps-api-3

I've tried to find a solution for 2 weeks but I can't find any information about it. Few general tutorials and Google Maps docs all say that you should cache them but noone tells how. Like it's something very obvious..

[image]

**How to acieve this caching shown on image?** What's the logic behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you save an array of objects with the co-oridnates and location as attributes and save as [HTML5 local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)? This way you could check through the array first and then if it's not there send an Ajax request after that.

Comment: Note that this _caching_ shouldn't be _permanent_ but only applies if you don't reload the page. Everything should go back to normal if page is reloaded. I think that I could add all loaded markers to an array of already loaded markers/points.. But how do you think I should check if it's already shown on map? How should I check that array efficiently? Please note that there are thousands of markers.. I would appriciate a small code example.

Comment: If the caching should only last while the page isn't reloaded then a global array of objects with the data stored there should work. Then just use a for loop to go through the array and if by the end the location you're looking for hasn't been found then you can send the ajax request. Thousands of markers is going to use up a chunk of memory though...

Comment: Could I use map bounds/grid as caching? For example, if some location on map is seen, load all markers on that grid and push the grid to an array . Then array is much shorter and loop should be ease. Only problem is that this is rather Google Maps specific and I don't know anything about it. Have you worked with it or should I start to learn from 0?

Comment: I've never used it for anything like this but best of luck with it anyway!